# Java Regex First Name Validation

Tags: java, regex, validation

I understand that validating the first name field is highly controversial due to the fact that there are so many different possibilities. However, I am just learning regex and in an effort to help grasp the concept, I have designed some simple validations to create just try to make sure I am able to make the code do exactly what I want it to, despite whether or not it conforms to best business logic practices.

I am trying to validate a few things.

1. The first name is between 1 and 25 characters.
2. The first name can only start with an a-z (ignore case) character.
3. After that the first name can contain a-z (ignore case) and [ '-,.].
4. The first name can only end with an a-z (ignore case) character.

   ```
   public static boolean firstNameValidation(String name){

       valid = name.matches("(?i)(^[a-z]+)[a-z .,-]((?! .,-)$){1,25}$");

       System.out.println("Name: " + name + "\nValid: " + valid);

       return valid;
    }
   ```

Comment: Poor Günther :(

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: `(?<=[^a-z ',.-]|^)[a-z](?:(?:[a-z]|[ ',.-](?![ ',.-])){1,23}[a-z])?(?=[^a-z ',.-]|$)`. This will ensure that there is a non-name character or no character before the name (beginning of string), that the name consists of at least 1 alphabetic character, potentially followed by 1-23 of characters in the set `a-z ',.-` without two `' ,.-` characters following each other and then followed by an alphabetic character, followed by a non-name character or no character (end of string). Also, use the `i` modifier for case-insensitivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is almost correct. The following is a modification that satisfies all of the conditions:

```
valid = name.matches("(?i)(^[a-z])((?![ .,'-]$)[a-z .,'-]){0,24}$");
```

Comment: do you really need `^`  and `$` when using `matches`? and some explanation would be nice...

Comment: Thanks, I have a quick question. It seems kind of backwards when looking at it. Is there a reason you listed the negative look-ahead before the [a-z .,'-]?

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger This could have been written in different ways. I just modified the user's expression to satisfy some of the conditions it missed.

Comment: @oznomal Yes, because the look-ahead determines whether it's the last character that is to be matched and if that is, it's not one of those. It has to placed before matching the last character, because it is a "look ahead". If you put it afterwards, there's no character "ahead" of you to match. As Carlos Heuberger pointed out, you can also omit `^` and the last `$` when using matches.

Comment: sure it can be written in different ways, but I would like to know why use `^`  and `$` - is it needed? and, by the way, this expression also returns `true` for names (much) longer than 25 characters... but seems like that is OK for @oznomal (should correct the question)

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger I just tried to stick with the questioner's pattern as he is trying to learn where he could fix his pattern to make it work. As to your question whether it is "needed": No, it's not as I've mentioned above; it is correct with or without those markers. I edited to fix the issue with the length as I missed to remove the extra `+`

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex

```
^[^- '](?=(?![A-Z]?[A-Z]))(?=(?![a-z]+[A-Z]))(?=(?!.*[A-Z][A-Z]))(?=(?!.*[- '][- '.]))(?=(?!.*[.][-'.]))[A-Za-z- '.]{2,}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nMStwW/1)

Answer (score 0):

A regex for the same:

```
([a-zA-z]{1}[a-zA-z_'-,.]{0,23}[a-zA-Z]{0,1})
```

Comment: `{1}` really needed? I believe that `[a-zA-Z]` only matches one character by itself... the `-` inside of `[]` also has a special meaning, not sure if the author meant it... and this expression seams to match `"a_"`

Comment: This means the Name should end with a character.

Comment: but `"a_"`does not end with a character but your expression accept it! (or `"test,"`)

Comment: `([a-zA-z]{1}[a-zA-z_'-,.]{0,23}[a-zA-Z]{1})` this regex is correct or not.

Comment: what about one letter names?

Comment: Yes, this is a problem with this.

Comment: `{0,1}` is equivalent to `?` Also, as @CarlosHeuberger mentioned, you need to either escape the `-` as `\-` or put it at the end of the set

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger We can do this with two conditions `if([a-zA-z]{1}[a-zA-z_'-,.]{0,23}[a-zA-Z]{1}) || ([a-zA-Z)`

Answer (score 0):

Lets change the order of the requirements:

1. ignore case: `"(?i)"`
2. can only start with an a-z character: `"(?i)[a-z]"`
3. can only end with an a-z: `"(?i)[a-z](.*[a-z])?"`
4. is between 1 and 25 characters: `"(?i)[a-z](.{0,23}[a-z])?"`
5. can contain a-z and [ '-,.]: `"(?i)[a-z]([- ',.a-z]{0,23}[a-z])?"`

the last one should do the job:

```
valid = name.matches("(?i)[a-z]([- ',.a-z]{0,23}[a-z])?")
```

<del>Test on [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/) (press java button).</del>

Notes for above points

1. could have used `"[a-zA-Z]"' instead of`"(?i)"'
2. need `?` since we want to allow one character names
3. 23 is total length minus first and the last charracter (25-1-1)
4. the `-` **must** come first (or last) inside `[]` else it is interpreted as range sepparator (assuming you didn't mean the characters between `'` and `,`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this simplest version:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][-',.][a-zA-Z]{1,25}$
```

Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

A unicode compatible version of the answer of @ProPhoto:

`^[^- '](?=(?!\p{Lu}?\p{Lu}))(?=(?!\p{Ll}+\p{Lu}))(?=(?!.*\p{Lu}\p{Lu}))(?=(?!.*[- '][- '.]))(?=(?!.*[.][-'.]))(\p{L}|[- '.]){2,}$`